# Is it possible to use the jQuery-dependent library 'chessboard.js' with React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chessboard.js

I'm interested in using the [Chessboard.js library](http://chessboardjs.com/) with React.  However Chessboard.js uses jQuery, which React recommends against, although it seems [it's not completely forbidden](https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html).  I know that there are libraries that have [integrated Chessboard.js with React](https://github.com/mishfit/chessboardjs-react), but I don't know how successfully they've done so.

The proof is in the pudding, of course, and it would be possible to try out the various packages and see how they work.  But I'm relatively new to React, so I'd be keen to know if anyone had any good (or bad) experiences mixing Chessboard.js with React.

Comment: https://github.com/willb335/chessboardjsx

Comment: Thanks.  And to update the board position you'd set the value passed by the prop function `getPosition` as the as the position prop `position`, right?

Comment: Hmmm, I didn't used it ;) Probably `getPosition` can be used that way. In 'Stockfish' example positions (f.e. history) are stored in engine. Component draws view using `position` prop. Second prop, `onDrop` handler calls engine to prepare new move/updated position. New position stored in state (using setState) forces rerendering (using updated position).

Answer (score 1):

Sure it is possible. Return always false in shouldComponentUpdate and use jquery after placing your refs in componentDidMount.
Ref: https://notes.devlabs.bg/how-to-use-jquery-libraries-in-the-react-ecosystem-7dfeb1aafde0